# How to check original number equals reverse or not

Tags: java

In this code why we write `orig=num`; what is the purpose to write this? Because when I delete `orig=num`; I get only is not equal. Can you explain that part?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int num, orig, rev=0, rem;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       
    System.out.print("Enter a Number : ");
    num = scan.nextInt();
       
    orig=num;
       
    while(num>0)
    {
        rem = num%10;
        rev = rev*10 + rem;
        num = num/10;
    }
    if(orig == rev)
    {
        System.out.print("Reverse is Equal to Original");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("Reverse is not Equal to Original");
    }
}
```

Comment: "orig" is probably short for "original number" and used to safe the number that is entered by the user because "num" gets modified and you need some variable to safe the original entered number.

Comment: [Palindrome in java](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/examples/palindrome-number)

Answer (score 1):

When you write `orig=num`; it sets the `orig` variable to the same value as `num = (scan.nextInt();` (your input)).

The num variable in the while loop acts as a *counter* variable.
In general, you scan the input, and then you loop over it a certain a amount of times.

Answer (score 1):

In `orig` you are storing a copy of an original number, and then you are reversing the `num` and storing it to `rev` and making `num` to 0, thus at the end you have to compare with `orig` with `rev` to check if the reverse is equal to the original number.

For Example :

```
num = 1234
orig = num // orig = 1234
```

then after *while* loop

```
while(num>0)
{
    rem = num%10;
    rev = rev*10 + rem;
    num = num/10;
}

num = 0 
rev = 4321
```

you are comparing `orig` with `rev` to check if they are the same or not.